# Selling files through Ethereum

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to make an Ethereum contact that accepts ether and gives a key if the payment is enough. Obviously, the key needs to be private until the user pays, but I want this to be a contact such that the user can be sure he'll receive the files in exchange of money.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem:

**Part 1 - Initialization**

Each of the files is encrypted with a different key. The keys (concatenated to some fixed data to verify decryption) are then reencrypted each with a different key, K1[i], and the resulting array E1 is sent to the buyer. The seller signs each of E1 individually and sends the resulting signature array S1, to the buyer.

The seller also sends the array E2, produced by encrypting each of K1 individually, all with the same key, K2. The buyer signs each of E2 individually and sends the resulting signature array, S2, to the seller.

At this point, the buyer has E1, an individually encrypted key array, and E2, the encrypted collection of keys required to decrypt E1. The buyer can prove E1 comes from the seller and the seller can prove the buyer received E2.

**Part 2 - Verification**

The buyer will then ask for some sample keys (he picks some files), to make sure the keys stored in E1 are actually correct and that the files are not fake. The buyer proceeds only if satisfied.

At this point, the buyer trusts that decrypting E1 will give him access to the files.

**Part 3 - Payment**

The buyer sends ether to the contract. He is able to withdraw it until the seller sends K2 to the contact. At that point, a timestamp is stored and a time window is given to the buyer during which he can verify the files and make accusations. If no accusations are made, the seller receives the money.

**Part 4 - Accusations**

If the buyer claims that one of E1 (E1[i]) is still undecryptable, he sends E1[i] and S1[i] to the contract. If the signature is valid, the seller will have a time window to disprove the accusation by providing E2[i] and S2[i]. If K2 decrypts E2[i] into a K1[i] that decrypts E1[i], and the signature is valid, the accusation is false and the seller receives his money. If the seller fails to disprove the accusation on time, the buyer is refunded.

The buyer may not make more than one accusation, to avoid scamming the seller by spamming him with too many to disprove; a failed accusation completes the transaction immediately.

---

Old answer, which had several flaws:

- Everything is public, meaning that the files can't be publicly hosted and must be encrypted differently for each buyer
- A large number of files makes a lot of data transfer
- Verifying many keys uses a lot of gas. The new answer will only verify keys in case of an accusation

Each file will be encrypted with a different key. The keys will also be used to encrypt a series of test messages that will be stored by the contact. The buyer will then ask for a sample key (he chooses one file), to make sure the keys stored are actually correct and that the files are not fake.

When enough ether is sent to the contact, the seller has a certain amount of time to give the full set of private keys, which will then be checked by the contact. If one of the test messages still fails to decrypt once the time limit is reached, the buyer can withdraw his money.

Comment: Curious to see the source code. Can you please share?

Comment: @niksmac: I have no source code yet. Also, I just modified the protocol a bit to avoid sending too much data and using a lot of gas

Comment: Be aware that doing aes encryption in solidity is expensive. Also the data processed in a contract is public and can be inspected by anyone with access to the blockchain.

Comment: @Ismael: My updated answer actually does no decryption as long as there is no disagreement (money gets transferred into contact and seller withdraws once time limit for accusation expires). Only in case of an accusation the contact will do decryptions for a single key to check who's right.

Comment: Just to clarify: Parts 1 and 2 are not done using the contract. The cryptography is done by the buyer and seller and all transfers are done directly between them

Comment: @Someone Can you explain how the verification is done in part 2?